# Efficiently saving many consecutively recorded images in C++

Tags: c++, image, save

**I am facing the following problem:**
I use a C++ program to control a scientific camera that is connected to my PC. It takes photos with short shutter times as fast as possible (ca. 1sec per image).

At its current stage, the program saves each photo to the hard drive immediately after it has been made. It appears, that the `I/O` access takes a lot of time (ca. 1/2 s per saving) which drastically lowers the image rate.

I've been thinking about storing many images first (say, in an array) and then save them all in one batch.
Would that work? Are there any good alternatives? How would one handle such a problem?

Making a video instead of an image is not an option.

Thank you very much

EDIT: Here is the code I am using:

```
    // capture loop: add up 'preint' images read out with 12 bit adc resolution
    // and save them as 16 bit image

    // read out current shutter register
    // read the 32-bit hex value into the unsigned long member of the above defined union
    cam.ReadRegister( 0x918, &curShutter.ulValue );
    fCurShutter = curShutter.fValue;

    cout << "Grab # " << ip.cnt << "; Serv: " << ip.servopos << "; Expt: " << ip.exptime << "; T: " << ip.temp  << "; prog " ;

    //inner capture loop
    for ( int imageCnt=0; imageCnt < ip.preint; imageCnt++ )
    {
        error = cam.RetrieveBuffer( &monoImage );
        if (error != PGRERROR_OK){PrintError( error ); continue;}

        cout << "." ;

        //convert to cv::Mat image
        unsigned int rowBytes = (double)monoImage.GetReceivedDataSize()/(double)monoImage.GetRows();
        cv_image = cv::Mat(monoImage.GetRows(), monoImage.GetCols(), CV_16UC1, monoImage.GetData(),rowBytes);

        cv_sum_image = cv_sum_image + cv_image/ip.preint;

        cv::imshow("image", cv_sum_image);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }

    //t=GetTickCount() - t;
    unsigned int shutterus = fCurShutter*1000000;

    {
    //create filename and save co-added image
    ostringstream filename;
    filename << ip.mode <<"_"<< ip.cdt << "_"   << setfill('0') << setw(5) << ip.cnt << "_" << ip.servopos << "_" << setfill('0') << setw(6) << shutterus << "_" << ip.preint << "_" << ip.temp << "_" << ip.pres <<".pgm";
    //cv::string ss = filename.str();
    string ss = filename.str();
    cv::imwrite(ss,cv_sum_image);
    }

    // Stop capturing images
    error = cam.StopCapture();
    if (error != PGRERROR_OK){PrintError( error ); return -1;}

    // Disconnect the camera
    error = cam.Disconnect();
    if (error != PGRERROR_OK){ PrintError( error ); return -1;}

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe the issue lies within the opencv routine?

Comment: How large are the images? Is getting a better storage medium an option (e.g. SSD, memory card)?

Comment: What OS are you using? By default, Linux will "write" to disk asynchronously. The write call will copy the data into a buffer and return control to your program very quickly, then the kernel will write the data physically to disk sometime later.

Comment: I would consider putting multiple images into each file - it may help reduce the disk heads jumping around;  also - how many images do you need to record?  If you can fit it all in memory then just do that and then dump to disk at the end.

Comment: In general, you want to look at your data rate (bytes/sec), your hardware setup, and what else is accessing the disk. I'm surprised by how slow you're reporting. My guess is that you might have a slow HDD and/or other programs accessing disk heavily and/or a slow CPU and/or _very_ large images, probably on Windows. The fix will depend on which combination of these factors are in your case.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you are saving your files? Are you using fwrite or ofstream or something else? Also, What OS is this on? How large are your image files?

Comment: Thanks for your replies!
Image size: 601 MB. I am looking at creating a few thousand of these images. Linux is not an option, since I am bound to Windows due to driver restrictions... :/

Comment: Sorry - 601 KB of course.

Comment: @JMAA _Linux will "write" to disk asynchronously_ And so will Windows.  And macOS.  And...

Comment: 600kb/s is nothing.  It's a drop in the ocean.  A speck on the horizon.  A, erm, you get the idea.  This problem should not be happening, **please post your code back to your question** (else it's going to get closed).  Maybe the time is actually spent compressing the image or something.  Thanks,

Comment: @PaulSanders
Thanks for the clarification, I mostly develop for linux so wasn't willing to comment on the others

Comment: @JMAA Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the most likely culprit is the openCV imwrite function.
You should be aware that imwrite is also encoding your output, based on the provided filename extension (in your case, .pgm).

The PGM format is quite simple in nature, but looking at the openCV code there is some processing going on, and the data is processed one byte at a time, which can maybe explain the slowness you are seeing.

I would, firstly, try to use a simpler file format, just to verify that the imwrite function is indeed the problem. Open CV can write files in a .bmp format, and the encoder for this looks much simpler, and should be faster.

If this hypothesis is confirmed, you have quite a few possible courses of action. A few from the top of my head:

1. As in your question, delay the writing to the file until after your time-sensitive operations are done. This make sense in general, but you most probably won't be able to fit all your images in memory ( around 600mb per 1000 images you want to do).
2. Create a dedicated thread for your file storage operations, and offload the work to this other thread.
3. Store the images as fast as you can on the HDD (either in the .bmp format, or implement your own file writer, that just dumps the objects from memory to the hdd), and later post-process them to the format that you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I thought storing the files in a pgm file would be least time-intensive, since it is such a "trivial" file format. I will try your suggestions out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the strong delay was caused due to broken hardware. The cable we used didn't allow for a sufficient data stream.

Comment: Please add more description.

Comment: The cable was literally broken and data stream was reduced. We found this out by simply replacing the cable and didn't bother to investigate further into what the actual issue was with the old cable.